# Count consecutive elements in a same length vector

Tags: r, vector, count, sequence, run-length-encoding

If I have a vector like

```
"a": 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

How can I generate a vector of the same length containing the count of consecutive elements, like so:

```
"b": 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

I tried rle, but I did not manage to stretch it out this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another option using `rle` and `rep`

```
with(rle(a), rep(lengths, times = lengths))
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

**data**

```
a <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a grouping variable using `diff` and use it in `ave` to calculate `length` of each group.

```
ave(x, cumsum(c(0, diff(x) != 0)), FUN = length)
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

You can do the same with `dplyr` `lag`

```
library(dplyr)       
ave(x,cumsum(x != lag(x, default = FALSE)), FUN = length)
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

---

And for completeness with `data.table` `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
ave(x, rleid(x), FUN = length)
#[1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

**data**

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `vapply`

```
count_consec <- function (a) {
  # creating output vector out
  out <- integer(length(a))

  # consecutive differences
  diffs <- which(diff(a) != 0)

  # returning 0 just in order to have a return statement in vapply - you can return anything else
  vapply(1:(length(diffs)+1), function (k) {
    if (k == 1) {
      out[1:diffs[1]] <<- diffs[1]
      return (0L)
    }
    if (k == length(diffs)+1) {
      out[(diffs[k-1]+1):length(out)] <<- length(out) - diffs[k-1]
      return (0L)
    }
    out[(diffs[k-1]+1):diffs[k]] <<- diffs[k] - diffs[k-1]
    return (0L)
  }, integer(1))
  out
}
count_consec(a)
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 2 2 3 3 3
```

with the data `a <- as.integer(unlist(strsplit('0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0', ' ')))`