# Using rle() for indexing data.frame - how to show zero's in the function to maintain the same vector length?

Tags: r, dataframe, run-length-encoding

In the following example, my goal is to show years in which consecutive numbers in `df` transposed to `df_new` are lower than `threshold` of `-1.2` in `5` consecutive instances. I want to then return corresponding unique values from column `df_new$year` as result. My problem linking `rle()` function result is that the length does not correspond to `df_new$year` length and thus I can't index it properly. The issue with `rle()` function is that it does not return zero's and thus it returns only runs of at least 1 value below the `threshold` in `k`. How can I improve this bit of code to achieve what I need? Is there a way to force rle() to include zero's in `k` or shall I go with another approach?

```
# Example reproducible df:
set.seed(125)
df <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V2=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V3=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V4=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V5=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V6=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V7=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V8=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V9=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5),
                 V10=rnorm(10,-1.5,.5))
library(data.table)
df_t <- t(df)
df_long <- melt(df_t)
df_long$year <- rep(1976:1985, each=nrow(df))
df_new <- data.frame(value=df_long$value,year=df_long$year)

# Threshold values:
 threshold = -1.2
    consecutiveentries = 5
    number <- consecutiveentries-1
# Start of the problem:
    k <- rle(df_new$value < threshold)
    years <- unique(df_new$year[k$lengths > number])
```

Current result:

```
> years
[1] 1976 1978 1979 1980 1982 1984 1985
```

What I would like it to be:

```
> years
    [1] 1976 1980 1983 1985
```

Comment: Is the question only about the last two lines of your code (more or less)? If so, can you revise your question, post `df_new$value` and `df_new$year` and show expected output based on the input?

Comment: @markus I amended the question to make it more clear, but left the reproducible df as it was

Comment: Regarding the length of `rle` output and `df_new$year` - does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072409/count-consecutive-elements-in-a-same-length-vector/54072493

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ugly but it works :)

```
df_new$year[cumsum(k$lengths)[which(k$lengths >= 5)-1]+1]
```

**Each part:**

`idx <- which(k$lengths >= 5)-1` gives you the indices of `k$lengths` right before a value is higher or equal to 4.

With `cumsum(k$lengths)` we then build the cumulated sum over `k$lengths` and take the elements at `idx`. As a result we have the number of rows that occur before the first row that is part of a `>=5` sequence.

Adding 1 to this result gives us the indices of the rows where each sequence begins.

Comment: Great @Martin Schmelzer! Can you explain why it works??

Comment: Is this sufficient? :)